# OrCAD/Allegro PCB design

Tags: pcb, homework, allegro

I am required to design a PCB in Allegro for this circuit:

[image]

The problem is that our teacher believes that we have too much free time so our introduction into Allegro was close to none. I have searched the internet and found some videos and documents regarding my issues but I can't be certain that everything is actually ok! Furthermore I have two problems I couldn't solve at all:

1. As seen, there is a potentiometer in the design. I found a PCB footprint, downloaded it (it actually had a tutorial video attached and followed it) but I got this error:

[image]

2. I was told that I am required to put two fiducial markers on my PCB but I couldn't find the PCB editor everyone apparently has when using OrCAD!

For more information this is what I came up with:

[image]

and these are all the instructions that I have received:

> For SMT & PCB technology, the circuit will be made in the form of an electronic module whose interconnect structure (PCB) will comply with the following design requirements:
>
> - PCB dimensions: 40mm x 40mm;
> - Material FR4, double layer/ copper foil thickness 18 μm, plate thickness 1.5 mm;
> - All components will be placed on the upper side of the plate, TOP;
> - Passive components SMD chip 0805;
> - Only bipolar transistors and TEC-MOS can be used in SMD capsules (SOT 23, DPAK). TEC-J transistors can only be used if the need is justified
>   them.
> - Test points: circular, maximum 5 – justified by the test plan;
> - The origin (coordinate point (0,0)) will be placed in the lower-left corner of the printed wiring, so all project elements will have positive coordinates;
> - Against the edge of the plate, a clearance of 1 mm will be kept; they won't be components placed here, routes, texts, etc.;
> - The board will be provided with 2 global fiducial markers on the TOP layer, at a distance of 200 mil from the edge of the board, place conveniently; these markers will also exist on the layer Solder Paste Top (overlaid on TOP); will be used at the time of alignment template with the plate. The fiducial mark will be a circle with a minimum diameter of 1mm on the layer respectively, located in a circular space with a minimum diameter twice that of the inner circle, in which there will be nothing on any layer;
> - Greater attention will be paid to the Inscription Mask (Silk Screen) layer; this must not be found on component pads;
> - A new non-electric, MECHANICAL layer will be generated. It will contain: the outline of the board, the drilling drawing ("drill drawing") and the drilling table ("drill chart/table", "drill legend"), a cross-section through the designed printed circuit ("layer stack-up") and the mechanical information required for PCB manufacturing; 2 | 5
> - The gauge dimensions/plate dimensions must not be found on the electrical layer TOP; these, if any, will be placed on a mechanical non-electrical layer;
> - The plate will be provided with the identification elements of the designer (name, surname, group, PDCE I 2022-2023).
>
> The following widths are given for the interconnecting routes:
>
> - Current of 1A - 28 mil;
> - Current of hundreds of mA - 22 mil;
> - Signal - 18 mil. The spacing, in all cases, will be 12 mil. The through holes for signals (vias) will have a diameter of 0.4 mm.
>
> Gerber files - standard 274X and Excellon file must contain the following information:
>
> - Board outline;
> - TOP electric layer;
> - Electric layer BOTTOM;
> - Non-electric layer Printing mask (Silk Screen Top);
> - Non-electric layers Protective mask (Solder Mask Top and Bottom);
> - Non-electric Layer Template (Solder Paste Top);
> - Aperture list and drilling file.
>
> **NOTE!** Mandatory design requirements:
>
> a. PCB dimensions: 40mm x 40mm;
>
> b. Material FR4, double layer;
>
> c. The origin (coordinate point (0,0)) will be placed in the lower-left corner of the printed wiring board, so all elements of the project will have coordinates positive;
>
> d. The size of the routes and their spacing in accordance with the mentioned specifications.
>
> Design requirements aim at knowledge, compliance and application of IPC standards from the electronics industry in the realization of the electronic module for Project 1, as it follows:
>
> - IPC-2221A, "Generic Standard on Printed Board Design", regarding route routing conductors, conductor spacing, pad sizes for SMD components,
>   presence of marking and orientation of symbols, provision of test points and provision of bridges thermal (where applicable);
> - IPC-7527, "Requirements for Solder Paste Printing", for the deposition operation a contact pastes;
> - IPC-A-610, "Acceptability of Electronic Assemblies", for validating the operations of component placement and actual contact for module acceptability assembled electronics.

I would like at least to understand what I am doing instead of just messing around and hoping I found something close to a solution!

Answer (score 1):

1. The footprint you downloaded was made for a newer version of OrCad than what you are running and is not compatible.
   It's generally better to make your own footprints anyway, and I assume that this may be part of the assignment.
2. Create components which are fiducial markers, then place them in schematic and layout.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or something like that for creating a component as a fiducial marker?
And thank you very much for your answer